# Verifying two (simple) inequalities about projections

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $P$ an orthogonal projection onto a closed subspace of a hilbert space $X$, and let $x,y \in X$.

I am trying to prove the following two statements hold
\begin{align*}
&\|x-Py\|^2 \leq \|x-y\|^2 + \|x-Px\|^2, \\
&\|x-y\|^2 \leq \|x-Py\|^2 + \|x-Px\|^2 + 2\|y-Py\|^2.
\end{align*}
Fred has kindly helped me with the first one, but I am yet to manage the second. One idea I had was to try 
\begin{equation}
\|x-y\|^2 = \|x+y-(Px + Py)+ Px - Py|^2 = \|x+y - Px - Py\|^2 - \|Px + Py\|^2
\end{equation}
But it hasn't led me anywhere.

I would appreciate help with this second inequality!

Answer (score 3):

For the first statement observe that $(x-Px) \perp P(x-y)$, since $P$ is an orthogonal projection. We can assume that $P \ne 0$. Then we get with Pythagoras:

$||x-Py||^2=||(x-Px)+P(x-y)||^2=||(x-Px)||^2+||P(x-y)||^2$

$ \le ||x-Px||^2+||P||^2 \cdot||x-y||^2 =||x-Px||^2+||x-y||^2$,

since $||P||=1$.

The second statement is your turn !

Comment: I'm trying the second one now! Is it is a similar trick? I'm still trying to figure out where the $2$ comes in.

Comment: I had the idea of applying the first inequality with $Py$ instead of $y$, and since projections are idempotent, we would get $\|x-Py\|^2 \leq \|x-Py\|^2 + \|x-Px\|^2$, which looks closer to the form we are aiming for. I can't see how to finish this off though...

Comment: Would you mind giving me a hint for the second inequality, or if the approach I described above is useful at all? I've been trying for a while and am still stuck.